# Node js ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

It except an error with Node js and AJAX POST, The Node request cannot check if form data are correctly handled, always it drop to error  function,
any solution to check below AJAX NODE JS CODE

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/process_add',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#process_form').serializeArray(),
        success:function(data) {
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function(errorThrown,data) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});


router.post('/process_add', function(req, res, next) {

    var item = {
        name: req.body.name,
        content:req.body.content
    };

    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('data_collection').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Process added');
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what error message are you getting ?

Comment: Provide a more detaile subject/title please.

Comment: I am not sure, but i think u need to pass whole URL with localhost and port.

Comment: I don't think you can use jQuery on the serverside. Use http.request instead. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: after a closer inspection, it looks like you mix up frontend and backend code. Can you please separate them clearly and also include the error message as others suggested?

Comment: The error code parse error the result of alert (data) it seem data cannot be checked with ajax requested," added to this records are added to MongoDB collection", Main issue why Ajax cannot validate the data

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ('/') root for that api to Ajax request .post has (/process_add) hints not root for that api so if index is root ('index/process_add)

Comment: So if the router is mounted using `app.use('/index', router);`, for example, then the `url` will be `/index/process_add` and not `/process_add`.

Comment: Correct without that it is looking for app.use('/process_add')

Comment: I use root in context to the routes folder. Keep in mind if you do separate JS files for your app routing your "root" channel will change

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX request '/process_add' will point to the root of your URL.Say for example abc.com is your domain the endpoint here would be 'abc.com/process_add'.
Ensure your router exists in the root reference of '/' in app.Something like this

app.js

```
var index = require('./routes/index');    
app.use('/',index);
```

routes/index.js

```
    router.post('/process_add', function(req, res, next) {

        var item = {
            name: req.body.name,
            content:req.body.content
        };

        mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.collection('data_collection').insertOne(item, function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                console.log('Process added');
                db.close();
            });
        });
    });
```

Happy Coding!